# Angular 6 Accessing element inside array of objects using index

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am having array of objects that I received from restful webservice call. Below is the snippet of the array that I am getting from my restful web service.

```
[{"id":1,"wt":1,"wtName":"WT1","ct":"CT1","dtType":"DT1"},{"id":2,"wt":2,"wtName":"WT2","ct":"CT2","dtType":"DT2"},{"id":3,"wt":3,"wtName":"WT3","ct":"CT3","dtType":"DT3"},{"id":4,"wt":4,"wtName":"WT4","ct":"CT4","dtType":"DT4"},{"id":5,"wt":5,"wtName":"WT5","ct":"CT5","dtType":"DT5"},{"id":6,"wt":6,"wtName":"WT6","ct":"CT6","dtType":"DT6"}]
```

I am trying to iterate over this array in my Angular-6 html file to form a table. Below is the code snippet I am using to iterate over the array:

**Case - 1**

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records">
    <td>{{record[3]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Nothing is printed but if I do the following, then I am seeing the records are coming:

**Case - 2**

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records">
    <td>{{record.wtName}}</td>
</tr>
```

It will be really helpful if you can guide me what I need to do if I want to print the elements in the above array using index instead of their attribute name.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Why would you access object properties by index? You could, possibly, do it like `Object.keys(record)[3]`, but I would strongly advise against it. Object properties are not ordered.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ritaj. The reason being, I want to make this reusable. The attribute name can vary. That's why I wanted to access it based on the index.

Comment: You could add another field to your object which you will pass to the generic component. `[{"id":1,"wt":1,"wtName":"WT1", "fieldToShow": "wtName" ... `. And show the field like `<td>{{record[record[fieldToShow]]}}</td>`. Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts @ritaj. It was helpful.